# Windows 10 and precision touchpad in remote desktop session

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, synaptics-touchpad

On my personal notebook I have set "Three fingers gestures/taps" action to "Middle mouse button". Works as expected.

When I use remote desktop session to my workmachine, the gesture propagates and translates to "Win+P" command which spawns "Project" dialog.

I can't find any workaround for this. Both machines have win10 pro 64bit, notebook is Xiaomi Notebook Air 2018.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: no, would have posted it here.

Comment: Hi, try this: https://superuser.com/a/1601645/724321

Comment: solution posted by Eugen works.